# How to delete HTML section using a function of js?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to remove a HTML section using a button. The button is in the HTML section I want to remove. And the section I want to remove was previously added by a button.

With Add section button I add a section below the first section, but I can't create a function to remove a section, I can't select the section I want to remove.

[image of web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1kgv.png)

Comment: Welcome @Francisco, A snippet code will help us to better understand your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're able to use the remove() method in order to do that.

Example:

HTML:

```html
<div id="testID">your stuff.</div>

<button onclick="deleteDiv()">Delete</button>
```

JS:

```js
function deleteDiv() {
  var selectedDiv = document.getElementById("testID");
  selectedDiv.remove();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code:-

```
<p id ="remove" style = "color: green; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"> 
 on click remove this section
</p> 

<button onClick = "remove()"> 
   click here 
</button> 
var htmlElement = document.getElementById('remove'); //use getElemeyId or getElementsByClassName According to your need;
    
function remove() { 
  htmlElement.remove();
}
```